# Compact projection on Banach space has finite rank

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

> Let $E$ be a Banach space. Show that every compact projection has finite rank.

I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: If $P$ is a projection the image of the closed ball is the closed ball in the space you are projecting onto.

Comment: so, does that then mean the unit ball is compact? which means E is finite dimensional?

Comment: @Victoria that's correct.

Comment: But how can I proof this result? I haven't seen it anywhere :(

Answer (score 3):

Let $B\subset P(X)$ be a closed and limited subset in $P(X)$, if we have that B is compact, then $P(X)$ is finite-dimensional. We have $P^2=P$, then $P(B)=B$ and it implies that $\overline{P(B)}$ is compact, since $P$ is compact and $B$ is limited. 
Hence B is closed, then $\overline{P(B)}=\overline{B}=B$ and $B$ is compact, so $P(X)$ has finite rank.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the projection $\pi$ has infinite rank, and let $X:=\pi(E)$. Let $x_n$ be an orthonormal base of $X$. Clearly $x_n$ belong to the unit ball of $E$, but contains no Cauchy sequence.

Comment: I am afraid you can't talk about orthonormality in the general Banach-space setting.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I think a countable subset of a Schauder base of $X$ may work.

Comment: The existence of subspaces with a Schauder basis is non-trivial. Simply use the Riesz lemma for the range of $P$. (The range of $P$ need not have a basis.)

Comment: Ok, you're right, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If some Fredholm theory is assumed this is immediate. If $u: E \to E$ is a compact operator then $u-\lambda$ is Fredholm for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ (here we only need that $\ker(u-\lambda)$ is finite dimensional). Now let $p: E \to E$ be any compact idempotent, we have $p(E) = \ker(1 - p)$ and we are done.